# FireDAC Conversion not supported for query parameter on Interbase timestamp column

Tags: delphi, firedac, interbase

I'm having a problem opening a query that uses a timestamp parameter to an interbase table.  After checking stackoverflow and implementing the conversion mappings for MapRules, I get a result of "Conversion is not supported" when opening the query.

Any help is deeply appreciated, Thanks!

Here is the code that sets the parameters:

```html
    with FDQuery1 do
    begin
      Close;
      FDQuery1.FormatOptions.OwnMapRules := True;
      with FormatOptions.MapRules.Add do
      begin
        SourceDataType := dtDateTime;
        TargetDataType := dtDateTimeStamp;
      end;
      FDQuery1.Params.ParamByName('BalanceDate').AsDateTime := StrToDateTime('10/03/2017');
      FDQuery1.ParamByName('User').AsInteger := 1;
      FDQuery1.OpenOrExecute;
    end;
```

Here is the query:

```html
SELECT
 AC.ACCOUNT_ID,
 AC.ACCOUNT_NAME,
 ACT.ACCOUNT_TYPE_NAME,
 (Select Sum(P1.TOTAL_VAL) From PMNTDOCTRANS P1, DAYBATCH D1 Where
  (P1.ACCOUNT_ID=AC.ACCOUNT_ID)
  And (D1.DAY_BATCH_ID=P1.DAY_BATCH_ID)
  And (D1.DAY_BATCH_DATE <= :BalanceDate)
  And (D1.DAY_BATCH_STORE in (Select Id From ExtUserList Where List_Id=9 and User_Id =:User))
 ) As Val1,
 (Select Sum(P2.TOTAL_VAL) From PMNTDOCTRANS P2, DAYBATCH D2 Where
  (P2.OPOSIT_ACCOUNT=AC.ACCOUNT_ID)
  And (D2.DAY_BATCH_ID=P2.DAY_BATCH_ID)
  And (D2.DAY_BATCH_DATE <= :BalanceDate)
  And (D2.DAY_BATCH_STORE in (Select Id From ExtUserList Where List_Id=9 and User_Id =:User))
 ) As Val2
FROM
 ACCOUNT AC ,
 ACCOUNTTYPE ACT
WHERE
 (ACT.ACCOUNT_TYPE_ID = AC.ACCOUNT_TYPE_ID)
 And
 (AC.ACCOUNT_TYPE_ID in (Select Id From ExtUserList Where List_Id=3 and User_Id =:User))
ORDER BY ACCOUNT_TYPE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

this problem solves like this

```
FDQuery1.Params.ParamByName('BalanceDate').Value:= StrToDateTime('10/03/2017');
```